# Is it possible to make cdkTextareaAutosize animate smoothly?

Tags: angular, animation, textarea

I am using cdkTextareaAutosize to have my textarea resize automatically as the user types.
I have been trying to make the behavior smooth to avoid the jumps in the change of height.

I tried using simple CSS, as shown below, but this didn't work. cdkTextareaAutosize seems to set the height and bypass the CSS transitions.

```css
    textarea {
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: height 200ms;
    }
```

```html
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <textarea matInput
                  #textarea
                  autocomplete="off"
                  cdkTextareaAutosize
                  #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
                  cdkAutosizeMinRows="2"
                  [formControlName]="name"></textarea>
    </form>
```

Then I tried removing cdkTextareaAutosize and making it work programatically:

```js
        @ViewChild('textarea') textarea: ElementRef;


        constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

        ngOnInit(): void {

            this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
              (val: string) => {
                  this.renderer.setStyle(this.textarea.nativeElement, "height", 
  this.textarea.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px');
            )
          }
```

It somewhat works when the height increases, but never decreases.

Is there any solution to this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
I wrapped the textarea into a div container with fix height, overflow hidden, and CSS smooth transition on the height.
I listen to the textarea height change, and whenever there is a change, i copy the textarea height to the div container.